# Increase speed of CouchDB's _changes feed while applying a filter

Tags: couchdb

I'm having trouble with poor performance on CouchDB's `_changes` feed when there are multiple observers.

I have CouchDB running inside a virtual machine on a laptop, and multiple iOS clients are consuming `_changes?feed=continuous` on one of the databases over the network, using CouchDB's HTTP API. As the number of clients increases, the speed at which the changes come through is slowed to a crawl.

*N.B. I'm actually communicating with CouchDB via an Apache reverse proxy, which is compressing the responses.*

And I'm also noticing that, while applying a filter to the feed, it will often go long periods without delivering any changes to the HTTP stream. Almost as if I'm waiting for it to check a batch of documents that don't meet my filter.

Is there anything settings I can enable or optimisations I can make that will help speed this all up?

Comment: Will be interesting to see answers. I'm about to put up a solution that uses the changes but was thinking of having "one" consumer that consumes it and publish on own message queues and/or publishing using websockets etc.

Comment: That's not a bad idea. The filter I'm applying actually takes a variable parameter though, so I'd need multiple caches for the different possible filters. And I've already introduced loads of complexity using a reverse proxy just so I can get compressed content.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The increase of latency with the number of consumers of filtered _changes feed is no surprise when you realize, that for each change couchdb has ask the query server to evaluate the filter() function. Apparently it doesn't cache the results so it has to perform this operation for each consumer.

Something you could try is dropping the *filter* parameter and using the *include_docs=true* instead. This way the feed producer wouldn't have to ask the view server to evaluate the changes. This should make it more responsive. Of course, this comes with the price of significantly increasing the amount of data transferred in the feed and you have to duplicate the filter() function logic on the client side. Its not ideal, but I think its worth a shot.

Comment: I actually use the `include_docs` parameter already, because I'm using the changes feed as the *be-all-and-end-all* of getting data from Couch. Ideally I'd like to use `bulk_docs` to pull large quantities of data (being able to use views, which are faster), but it doesn't give me an update sequence so I wouldn't know where to start listening to the `_changes` feed. I might try this technique though and see if I get a performance improvement.

Comment: Its not faster, its sort of the same. `_changes` is a view as well. You can think about it as view generated with `emit(db_seq(doc), null)`. When you query it with `since` its like if you have used `startkey`. You should see a nice improvement of speed once you drop `filter` param.

Comment: I'm marking this as the answer due to the results of some testing. I timed the response in the terminal (`time curl ...`) and found that the filter increases the response by orders of magnitude. For ~6k documents the `_changes` response time was (on average) 4 seconds with no filter, and that jumped to 40 seconds with a filter applied.